# Check if a string is blank or doesn't exist in Scala

Tags: string, scala, scala-option

I have an `Option[String]`.

I want to check if there is a string exists and if it's exists its not blank.

```
def isBlank( input : Option[String]) : Boolean = 
{ 
     input.isEmpty || 
     input.filter(_.trim.length > 0).isEmpty 
}
```

Is there is a better way of doing this in Scala ?

Comment: I added a Scalafiddle to play with that: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/MLNE94O/10

Comment: That proves that the checked answer is not correct.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

What you should do is check using `exists`. Like so:

```
myOption.exists(_.trim.nonEmpty)
```

which will return `True` if and only if the `Option[String]` is not `None` and not empty.

Comment: this is not correct : 
scala> val myOption: Option[String]  = None
myOption: Option[String] = None

scala> myOption.exists(_.trim.nonEmpty)
res1: Boolean = false

Comment: As I understand he want it to be True on None. I like your short code, but it's exactly the inverse. Should be - myOption.forall(_.trim.isEmpty)

Comment: That also works. I avoid using forall in example code here due to the non-obvious implications on None.

Comment: This fails with null value. Any ideas how to set it up with possible null as well?

Comment: @KapilMalhotra if you have a `Some(null)` you're doing `Option` wrong. The `Option` constructor will automatically convert to a `None` if you use it. If, instead, you're passing a value into the `Some` constructor, you lose that safety guarantee.

Answer (score 6):

An approach based in pattern matching,

```
def isBlank( input : Option[String]) : Boolean = 
  input match {
    case None    => true
    case Some(s) => s.trim.isEmpty
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

`exists` (Accepted solution) will work when input has at least one element in it, that is `Some("")` but not when it's `None`.

**`exists` checks if at least one element(`x`) applies to function.**

eg.

```
scala> List[String]("apple", "").exists(_.isEmpty)
res21: Boolean = true

//if theres no element then obviously returns false
scala> List[String]().exists(_.isEmpty)
res30: Boolean = false
```

Same happens with `Option.empty`, as theres no element in it,

```
scala> Option.empty[String].exists(_.isEmpty)
res33: Boolean = false
```

**So `forall` is what makes sure the the function applies all the elements.**

```
scala> def isEmpty(sOpt: Option[String]) = sOpt.forall(_.trim.isEmpty)
isEmpty: (sOpt: Option[String])Boolean

scala> isEmpty(Some(""))
res10: Boolean = true

scala> isEmpty(Some("non-empty"))
res11: Boolean = false

scala> isEmpty(Option(null))
res12: Boolean = true
```

**The gross way is to filter `nonEmpty` string, then check `option.isEmpty`.**

```
scala> def isEmpty(sOpt: Option[String]) = sOpt.filter(_.trim.nonEmpty).isEmpty
isEmpty: (sOpt: Option[String])Boolean

scala> isEmpty(None)
res20: Boolean = true

scala> isEmpty(Some(""))
res21: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Nah, just change `exists(_.trim.nonEmpty)` to `forall(_.trim.isEmpty)`.

Comment: hoho, you are magic. I went the stupid route :) Thanks, updated answer

Answer (score 3):

This should work as well since filter of an empty Option results in an empty Option

```
def isBlank( input : Option[String]) : Boolean =  
   input.filter(_.trim.length > 0).isEmpty
```

Answer (score 2):

All proposed solutions will crash with NullPointerException if you pass:

```
val str : Option[String] = Some(null).
```

Therefore null-check is a **must**:

```
def isBlank(input: Option[String]): Boolean = 
  input.filterNot(s => s == null || s.trim.isEmpty).isEmpty
```

Comment: But you should never be passing `Some(null)`. It destroys the benefit of using `Option`!

Comment: It is public method and you never know, how someone might misbehave with your provided contract. Therefore, I think, it is always good to double check and not to step on nullPointer.

Answer (score 1):

I am from C# background and found Scala implicit methods similar to C# extensions

```
import com.foo.bar.utils.MyExtensions._
...

"my string".isNullOrEmpty  // false
"".isNullOrEmpty           // true
" ".isNullOrEmpty          // true
"  ".isNullOrEmpty         // true

val str: String  = null
str.isNullOrEmpty          // true
```

**Implementation**

```
package com.foo.bar.utils

object MyExtensions {

  class StringEx(val input: String) extends AnyVal {

    def isNullOrEmpty: Boolean =    
      if (input == null || input.trim.isEmpty)
        true
      else
        false
  }

  implicit def isNullOrEmpty(input: String): StringEx = new StringEx(input)
}
```

Comment: you can use implicit class btw:

  implicit class StringExtensions(val input: String) {
    def isNullOrEmpty: Boolean = input == null || input.trim.isEmpty
  }

Answer (score 1):

I added a Scalafiddle to play with that: [Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/MLNE94O/11)

That shows the marked correct answer is wrong (as pointed out by prayagupd):

```
def isBlank(str: Option[String]): Boolean =
   str.forall(_.trim.isEmpty)
```

the solution is for non-blank:

```
def isNotBlank(str: Option[String]): Boolean =
   str.exists(_.trim.nonEmpty)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also take advantage of [Extractor pattern](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html). It makes codes much more declarative.

For example:

```
object NonBlank {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[String] = Option(s).filter(_.trim.nonEmpty) 
}
```

And then use it like

```
def createUser(name: String): Either[Error, User] = name match {
  case NonBlank(username) => Right(userService.create(username))
  case _ => Left(new Error("Invalid username. Blank usernames are not allowed."))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also check using `lastOption` or `headOption`

if the string is empty it will return None

```
scala> "hello".lastOption
res39: Option[Char] = Some(o)

scala> "".lastOption
res40: Option[Char] = None
```

Comment: This addresses a `String` and not an `Option[String]` as requested. Also, an empty string, `""`, is not the same as a "blank" string (i.e. whitespace).

Comment: scala> "  ".lastOption
val res20: Option[Char] = Some( )

sorry that's not going to work