# value isBlank is not a member of String

Tags: scala, sbt, travis-ci

I am using sbt 1.2.6 to compile my project. In my local machine compilation runs fine, but when using travis-ci for testing, the compiler complains that `value isBlank is not a member of String`.

You can find the source code here
https://github.com/LukeDS-it/webfleet-driver/blob/679dff9877ea1edd403dc6cd3d55a22d5fd5328f/server/src/main/scala/it/ldsoftware/webfleet/driver/services/v1/AggregateService.scala#L138

And the build report here
https://travis-ci.com/LukeDS-it/webfleet-driver/builds/92441228

I have no more information to provide. My IDE says that everything is fine, and if I run compile or test in local everything works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: It does not compile on my local machine either. I am getting the same error. I noticed, that you have two branches. `master` compiles, `aggregates` does not compile. Are you sure, that you compile `aggregates` on your local machine too ?

Comment: Btw. `optional.isDefined &&  optional.get.isEmpty` can be written as `optional.exists(_.isEmpty)`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086493/check-if-a-string-is-blank-or-doesnt-exist-in-scala

Comment: Yes, I am working on that branch in local. Thanks for the suggestion about the option, I appreciate it, being somewhat new in Scala. I will try to do a clean build to see why this issue.

Comment: Yes, please try sbt clean and sbt compile.  No way,  that there is a isBlank method in your project. Do you import it to intellij?  Is the code valid there too?  Is it marked as an implicit conversion?

Comment: Okay I found out why it happens: it looks like I'm compiling against Java 11 on my machine, where that method has been introduced. Whereas on travis-ci the java version is lower.

Comment: You should create an answer yourself.  This is useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I had the idea of looking at the JavaDoc for `isEmpty` and found out that it says

> since: 11

On my machine I was compiling against Java11, whereas on Travis the java version was lower.